# decoding json dictionary with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

Ive got a script written to fetch data from an API, and return it, but now i need to parse that data, this is an example of what the json data looks like, with some of the dictionary values i am looking to pull.

```
{'results': [{'icpsr_id': 21133,
   'twitter_id': 'RepToddYoung',
   'thomas_id': '02019',
   'term_end': '2017-01-03',
   'office': '1007 Longworth House Office Building',
   'gender': 'M',
   'phone': '202-225-5315',
```

---

this is the code i have written to pull, and parse the json data file. could anyone tell me what is wrong with it? i am still returning the full value from the 'results' dictionary, Meaning it's like the code has done nothing, i still get the full dictionary, it isn't parsed instead of ***ONLY*** the 'twitter_id', and 'office'

```
import requests
import json

def call():
    payload = {'apikey':'my_apikey', 'zip':'74120'}
    bas_url = 'http://openstates.org/api/v1//legislators/?state=ok'
    r = requests.get(bas_url, params = payload)
    grab = r.json()
    return grab
    jsonResponse=json.loads(decoded_response)
    jsonData = jsonResponse["results"]
    for item in jsonData:
        chamber = item.get("twitter_id")
        last_name = item.get("office")
```

Comment: `call()` exits early because of `return grab` so everything after doesn't happen.

Comment: so, should i delete return grab entirely? or, just move it below the rest?

Comment: It depends on what you want your function to do.

Comment: It depends on you, what you want to return.

Comment: i ONLY want it to return the values that i call for EX 'twitter_id' , and 'office'

Comment: The sample data that you have posted is a Python dict, which is not valid JSON. You aren't trying to JSON parse that are you? To convert the string that you posted to a dict, use `ast.literal_eval`, after importing the ast module from the Python std lib (using `import ast`).

Comment: im sorry, ive posted multiple questions, trying to understand this and use the correct terms, but i guess ive been using incorect terms that are misleading people. see if this makes what i want any more clear, and then maybe youll have an answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994928/how-to-access-key-values-in-a-json-files-dictionaries-with-python

Comment: Posting the same question multiple times is heavily frowned on here in SO. Stick with the one question and add edits. Otherwise the whole database would be filled with fragmented discussions, of little use to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
def call():
    payload = {'apikey':'my_apikey', 'zip':'74120'}
    bas_url = 'http://openstates.org/api/v1//legislators/?state=ok'
    r = requests.get(bas_url, params = payload)
    grab = r.json()
    jsonData = grab["results"]
    return [{key: value for key, value in result.items() if key in ("twitter_id", "office")} for result in jsonData]
```

Comment: thaaaannnkkkk you!

Comment: Actually it appears that the value for 'results' is a list, so you probably want `return [{key: value for key, value in x.items() if key in ("twitter_id", "office")} for x in jsonData['results']]`.

Comment: @alykhank right you are, didn't think that through properly.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/Documents/congress.py", line 8, in call
    grab = r.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 808, in json

Comment: return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

sorry for the multiple comments, but it was the only way to give the full block

Comment: could someone provide me with a resource to the proper information i need to learn this?

Comment: Try just doing a small step at a time, instead of writing a lot of code and then having to guess where the errors might be. The traceback you posted as comments shows that the error happened in the call to `r.json()`. Are you sure this api returns a JSON string? Try printing `r.text` to see just what you are getting - if it is not valid JSON, then the `r.json()` method will raise an exception. More info on using the `requests` module is here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

Comment: C'mon man, you have to do some of the work here. What do you think "missing parentheses" is trying to tell you? You are using Python 3, so you can't write `print r.txt`, it has to be `print(r.text)`.

Comment: im sorry, ive been at it for awhile, and im used to py 2, im just mind numb to simple tasks. but, here is the exception raised 
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'txt'

Comment: No, meaning that is not called 'txt' but 'text' - see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at the online docs for the requests module, I see that calling `r.json()` will do the JSON parsing for you, and give you back a Python dict. The thing you are posting is the output of that dict, so the JSON part has already been taken care of for you.

This code should work in both Python 2 and Python 3, once you have extracted the data to json_response using `json_response = r.json()`:

```
extracted_values = []
json_data = json_response['results']
for item in json_data:
    subitem_dict = {}
    for key in 'twitter_id office'.split():
        subitem_dict[key] = item.get(key) # will give None if key does not exist
    extracted_values.append(subitem_dict)

print(extracted_values)
```

prints:

```
[{'twitter_id': 'RepToddYoung', 'office': '1007 Longworth House Office Building'}, 
 {'twitter_id': 'SenDonnelly', 'office': '720 Hart Senate Office Building'}, 
 {'twitter_id': 'SenDanCoats', 'office': '493 Russell Senate Office Building'}]
```